# Why __lib_start_main appear in array of string

Tags: c

Following are my code , just an example about strok

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define NUMBER_OF_STRINGS 10
int main(){
    char str[] = " SELECT CID FROM ACN WHERE ACN=:C1 AND ACCTNAME=:C2#/ROWS=30/USING=(C1=70,C2='OD100S')";
    char *strs[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS];
    int i = 0;
    for (char *p = strtok(str," "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
      if(i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS){
        strs[i] = malloc(strlen(p)+1);
        strcpy(strs[i], p);
        i++;
      } else {
          break;
      }   
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS ; i++){
        if(strs[i] != NULL)
            printf("%s\n",strs[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When print array of strs , I get

```
[root@prf01 /]# ./test
SELECT
CID
FROM
ACN
WHERE
ACN=:C1
AND
ACCTNAME=:C2#/ROWS=30/USING=(C1=70,C2='OD100S')
__libc_start_main
```

I have no idea why "__libc_start_main" string store in my array

Please help me to clear it ,thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading uninitialized pointer(s) which is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You only have `i` number of strings *after* the loop, *not* `NUMBER_OF_STRINGS` strings.

You can store the total number of strings in another variable after the loop and use it when you print it.

```
 for (char *p = strtok(str," "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
    ....
    }

   size_t num = i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < num ; i++){
        if(strs[i] != NULL)
            printf("%s\n",strs[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for(i = 0 ; i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS ; i++){
    if(strs[i] != NULL)
        printf("%s\n",strs[i]);
}
```

to

```
int j;
for(j = 0 ; j < i ; j++){
        printf("%s\n",strs[j]);
}
```

In your code you are always read all values of array of pointer, but some positions are not inited. That is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Another solution could be to add

```
memset(strs, 0, NUMBER_OF_STRINGS);
```

after array declaration to init the whole array to `NULL`. In this case you could leave the final loop as you coded it.